# Verification for a Proof By Contradiction concerning a 5-root being irrational

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I was asked to prove that for a non negative $m$ number, that is not a 5-th power of an integer, its 5-root, $\sqrt[5]m$ is not a rational number.
Thanks for any feedback.

Proof By Contradiction:

Suppose Not,

Assume that for a non-negative $m$ number, that is not a 5-th power of an integer, its 5-root $\sqrt[5]m$ is a rational number.

Being  a rational number we can say:$$\sqrt[5]m=\frac{p}{q}\quad \text{for}  \;p,q\in\Bbb{Z}\;\text{and}\:q\neq0$$
Then by algebra,$$m=\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^{5}\Rightarrow m=\frac{p^{5}}{q^{5}}$$
Consider when $\frac{p}{q}=n$, $n \in\Bbb Z$,

This is a contradiction with the fact that $m$ is not a 5-th power of an integer.

Hence, $\sqrt[5]{m}$ is not a rational number.

Comment: Your attempt stops making sense to me after $m=p^5/q^5$.

Comment: How can you be sure that $\frac{p}{q}$ will be an integer $n$?

Comment: It's not quite that easy.  For all you know, $mq^5$ could be the fifth power of an integer even though $m$ is not.  You need to use the prime factorization of $m$, just as is done to prove $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are on the right track, but you cannot consider when $p/q = n \in \mathbb Z$.

**HINT**

I guess you implicitly meant that $m$ is a non-negative integer. Then, we have:

$q^5 \cdot m = p^5$, where $m, q, p$ are non-negative integers, and $p$, $q$ are coprime with each other, or $p=1$ or $q=1$.

Can you continue?

Comment: Are you saying that from the fact m exists in Z+ and m>0, p,q >0,and that we can define p,q as coprime with each other. From this we have two cases: where p=1, or q=1?

Comment: @MAC No, I mean since p/q is a rational number, then q,p are either coprime; or q = 1; or p = 1. For each scenario, you could check for your equation, and you’ll find that only when q=1 will make you equation solvable, but in that case, m is 5-th power of an integer

Answer (score 2):

You may assume (wlog) that $q\gt 0$, so since $p^5/q^5=m\in\Bbb Z$, this implies $q^5\mid p^5$. You can furthermore assume (wlog) that $\gcd(p,q)=1$. This would imply that $q\mid p$, so $1=\gcd(p,q)=q$ but then $m=p^5$ leading to a contradiction that $m$ is a 5th power of an integer, namely $p$

---

In fact, this argument can be generalized to $\sqrt[n]m$ where $m$ is not a perfect $n^\text{th}$ power